# Dynamically replace string value in configuration file

Tags: shell

I'm building a shell script to install apache-airflow and update some configurations for local development.

I would like to replace the value of property `dags_folder`. How can I replace it using shell script?

Here is what I've tried:

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
    SED_EXTRA=" "
else
    SED_EXTRA=""
fi

sed -i${SED_EXTRA}'' "s,dags_folder = ,dags_folder = banana,g" ~/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

It's almost working but I want to replace entire value. Is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sed` at all. Use `ed`, which won't require OS-specific changes to the invocation.

You want to match the entire line, not just the `name =` prefix, so add `.*` to the regular expression.

```
ed ~/airflow/airflow.cfg <<EOF
s,dags_folder = .*,dags_folder = banana,g
wq
EOF
```

Comment: It won't work. Still the same value, I've pasted your code into my shell script

Comment: What does `airflow.cfg` actually look like? It sounds like the regular expression is just wrong, and we can't suggest a replacement without knowing what actually needs to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Match up until the end of the line with `.*` regex

```
sed -i${SED_EXTRA}'' 's,dags_folder = .*,dags_folder = banana,g' ~/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one if I understand your issue correctly :)

```
var1="dags_folder ="
var2="dags_folder = banana"

sed -i 's/'"$var1"'/'"$var2"'/g' path to your cfg file
```